# Adjust timezone for dates in Wave Analytics

Tags: analytics

Research on the web hasn't proven much help.
I've found the idea of what to do, but no actual "put this code here and reference this".  I'm not a developer and don't understand JSON.

What I know:

The Source needs to be updated to the correct Opportunity source name.
Anything else?
WHERE does this section go in the JSON code?

```
"Extract_Opportunity": {
 "action": "computeExpression",
 "parameters": {
 "source": "Digest_Opportunity",
 "mergeWithSource": true,
 "computedFields": [
  {
   "name": "CreatedDateNew",
   "type": "Date",
   "format": "MM/dd/yyyy",
   "saqlExpression": "toDate(CreatedDate_sec_epoch - 8*3600)"
  }
  ]
 }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you add it via the Data Manager.

[image]